# Making custom, single-character directory mappings like ~ > $HOME

Tags: linux, bash

We all know that `~` maps to `$HOME` or `/home/user`.

Is it possible to make other mappings like this on other characters (@,_)?

A possible workaround I thought of was to use variables (which require at least two characters)...

```
H=/run/media/user/Storage
cp $H/file.txt .
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: A workaround could be to make a function and bind it to a particular key, maybe `Ctrl+z` (I know that's 2 key strokes but you could find a good alternative, I like to put my `ñ` to good use). So, this way you type `cd ñ`, the 'ñ' isn't echoed and instead it turns your current line in something like `cd /run/media/user/Sterage/` so you just keep going from there. That is easy with `zsh`, I'm sure it's also possible with bash.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible on a Mac and Linux

**On Mac**

- /Users/[yourusername]/.bash_profile

Note: You should also be able to use .profile file, but I do not use it. I just use .bash_profile, because it more specific, like *.bashrc* on linux, rather than *.cshrc*.

**Instructions**

Make a directory mapping (set a variable) to the desktop.

1. In Terminal.app, run

   `nano ~/.bash_profile OR nano $HOME/.bash_profile`
2. Add the following somewhere in your file.

   `[nameofvariable]="$HOME/Desktop"`

   (for example, pathtodesktop="$HOME/Desktop")
3. Quit Terminal and restart or run

   `source ~/.bash_profile`

Finished! Your new variable should function just like $HOME or ~, except to whichever path you choose.

In order to test it you could run:

```
cd $pathtodesktop
```

---

**On Linux**
Just follow the same instructions, except the file you want to edit is under $HOME/.bashrc or $HOME/.bash_profile.

---

**Above and Beyond the Question**
If you have a command that you frequently run, you could create an alias in your .bash_profile as well like this:

```
alias dt="cd $HOME/Desktop"
```

Refresh your terminal paths by restarting terminal or with

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Type just *dt* and your path should change to the Desktop

Answer (score 0):

In bash, no. I'm not aware of any shells which provide such a feature.

Comment: You could have just added this as a comment...

Comment: It's a factually correct answer: `bash` does not have a way of defining additional `~`-like shortcuts.

Comment: Facts require a source. You said, "In bash, no. 'I'm' not aware" this leads the reader to believe this is your opinion. Heck, I can go to any question on this site I don't know the answer to and write the same thing you wrote while being technically correct. A simple link would make this answer worthwhile.

Comment: Not trying to start a problem your answer just showed up in the review queue.