# Can I make a custom "directory alias" like '~' in bash?

Tags: bash

In bash I can go to my home directory with `cd ~` and actually refer to my home directory with any command with `~`.

Can I make new, custom "directory aliases" (?) to refer to other directories? Hypothetical example:

```
make_alias "~~" /mnt/photon/work/foo_project/

cp ~/home.png ~~/set_8/home_4.png
```

How it can be done, if so? If it cannot, is it by design and why so?

Nice to have: Where and how `~` is set and bound to this "~"?

Comment: Not particularly helpful to you, but you **can** do that with global aliases in.... ZSH, but not BASH. : **alias -g ~~='/mnt/photon/work/foo_project/'**

Comment: @SuperMagic: I like global aliases, too. But in the second example (cp ~~/set...) they will fail. Named directories are more appropriate: `n=/mnt/photon/work/foo_project` and then `cp foo ~n/bar`. (Note for the OP: Also limited to zsh).

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question asks about *single character* remappings (`@` or `_`), which isn't possible in bash, while `~~` certainly is (hacky, but possible). Also, it doesn't answer how this remapping is done.

Comment: The related question was: http://superuser.com/questions/541767

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The tilde is not an alias, it's part of bash's shell expansion (just like `*.txt` or `$((1 + 2))`).

[Bash tilde expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html#Tilde-Expansion) supports the following tilde-prefixes:

```
~            The value of $HOME

~/foo        $HOME/foo

~fred/foo    The subdirectory foo of the home directory of the user fred

~+/foo       $PWD/foo

~-/foo       ${OLDPWD-'~-'}/foo

~N           The string that would be displayed by `dirs +N'

~+N          The string that would be displayed by `dirs +N'

~-N          The string that would be displayed by `dirs -N'
```

[`dirs`](http://ss64.com/bash/dirs.html) uses the directory stack. You can use [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/bash/pushd.html) to add a directory to it.

To answer your specific question about `~~`, yes, it is *possible* to map a directory to it. Just create a user called `~` and set `/mnt/photon/work/foo_project/` as its home directory:

```
sudo useradd '~'
sudo sed -i 's#:/home/~:[^:]*$#:/mnt/photon/work/foo_project:/bin/false#' /etc/passwd
```

Of course, a much "saner" approach is just defining a shell variable that points to your directory in your `~/.bashrc` with the command

```
foo=/mnt/photon/work/foo_project
```

which can be accessed via `$foo`, as usual.